# Footer does not stay at bottom with shared layout in ReactJS, SASS and React-Router-6

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I know this has been asked multiple times and I have tried almost all of the solutions I could find but it hasn't worked out for me.
I am creating a multipage React Js application and I am routing them through React-router-6. I have created a shared layout that is below;

```
<>
    <div data-theme={theme}>
      <div className="app-container" >
        <Navbar changeTheme={changeTheme} currentTheme= {theme}/>
      </div>
        <Outlet/>
      <div className="app-container">
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </div>
</>
```

The Sass is as below:

```
.app-container {
    background-color: var(--background);
    font-family: var(--font-family);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    padding: 1rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
    @media screen and (min-width:280px) and (max-width:1080px){
        padding: 0;
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the footer for the home page at the end of the page but if I route it to another page, I get the footer in the middle of the page just after the content like this:
[image: Footer does not stick to bottom]

Scss for footer

```
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
    margin-top: auto;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
```

I tried the solution of providing a min-height - footer height.
I tried giving it an absolute positioning and bottom: 0, it works for other pages but does not work for the home page. The footer is placed on the other contents and not at the end.
Someone please provide a valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

Creating a page container for the whole body and then giving a flex of 1 for the contents inside the layout.

For layout:

```
<>
    <div data-theme={theme} className="page-container">
      <div>
        <Navbar changeTheme={changeTheme} currentTheme= {theme}/>
      </div>
      <div className='content-wrap'>
        <Outlet/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </div>
</>
```

and the CSS for layout is as below:

```
.page-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
.content-wrap {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Worked like a charm.